# Obtener medias de estudiantes en diccionarios python

Tags: python, python-2.7

estoy con un ejercicio de python con diccionarios, el de los estudiantes LLoyd, Alice y Tylor(lo escribo porque ya lo he visto en algunas de las preguntas, tengo que hacer la media, mi idea es meter todas las calificaciones de las distintas tareas en una sola lista y aplicar la función sum y dividirlo por la longitud de la lista, lo que no entiendo es cuando creo el bucle for para los valores de cada clave y especifico que si uno de los elementos es string no los incluya en la nueva lista, la lista resultante no atiende a esa orden y no sé el motivo, expongo el código:

```
 lloyd={
 'name':'Lloyd',
 'homework':[90.0,97.0,75.0,92.0],
 'quizzes':[88.0,40.0,94.0],
 'tests':[75.0,90.0]
 }
 alice={
 'name':'Alice',
 'homework':[100.0,92.0,98.0,100.0],
 'quizzes':[82.0,83.0,91.0],
 'tests':[89.0,97.0]
 }
 tyler={
 'name':'Tyler',
 'homework':[0.0,87.0,75.0,22.0],
 'quizzes':[0.0,75.0,78.0],
 'tests':[100.0,100.0] 
 }

 def media():
     lista_lloyd=[]
     for i in lloyd.values():
         if i is not str:
             lista_lloyd.extend(i)
     print lista_lloyd
     return
 media()
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:
[88.0, 40.0, 94.0, 75.0, 90.0, 'L', 'l', 'o', 'y', 'd', 90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]

No entiendo por qué no discrimina los string.
Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería. Un saludo

Comment: `i is not str` no es la forma de mirar el tipo. Puedes usar `if type(i) != str` o tambien `if not isinstance(i, str)`

Comment: Al margen de la pregunta, python 2.7 está obsoleto y se desaconseja su uso. A menos que sea un requisito de tu problema te recomendaría pasarte a una versión 3.x Desde la 3.4 tienes además implementado en la librería estándar la función `statistics.mean()` para obtener la media de una lista.

Answer (score 1):

```
class D():
    lloyd={
     'name':'Lloyd',
     'homework':[90.0,97.0,75.0,92.0],
     'quizzes':[88.0,40.0,94.0],
     'tests':[75.0,90.0]
     }
    alice={
     'name':'Alice',
     'homework':[100.0,92.0,98.0,100.0],
     'quizzes':[82.0,83.0,91.0],
     'tests':[89.0,97.0]
     }
    tyler={
     'name':'Tyler',
     'homework':[0.0,87.0,75.0,22.0],
     'quizzes':[0.0,75.0,78.0],
     'tests':[100.0,100.0] 
     }

def media():
    lista_lloyd=[]
    for i in D.lloyd.values():
        if type(i) != str:
            lista_lloyd.extend(i)
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(lista_lloyd)):
        total += lista_lloyd[i]
    res = total / len(lista_lloyd)
    return round(res, 2)

print(media())
```

El resultado es (media): 82.33

La forma correcta de saber si un valor es string es `type(i) == str`, que devuelve True si `i` es un string y False si es cualquier otro tipo de dato. Como quieres que se ejecute `lista_lloyd.extend(i)` solo si el tipo de dato es diferente de string, debes escribir `if type(i) != str:`

Además para calcular la media, no debes devolver solo la suma de los valores, sino la suma de los valores entre el número de valores. Para mostrar solo 2 decimales del resultado, puedes usar `round(res, 2)`